# How to limit an integer's input to 2-12 only?

Tags: c, input, limit

I want to strictly limit a user's input on an integer in this program to 2-12 only. How do I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    int diceThrown, diceResult;
    int sum = 0; 
    for(diceThrown = 1; diceThrown <= i; diceThrown++){
        scanf("%d", &diceResult);   //limit this input to 2-12 only, how?
        sum += diceResult;
    }
    if(sum >= 40){
        sum = sum % 40;
        if(sum == 12){
            printf ("28\n");
        } else if(sum == 35){
            printf ("7\n");
        } else{
            printf ("%d\n", sum);
        }
    } else if(sum < 40){
        if(sum == 12){
            printf ("28\n");
        } else if(sum == 35){
            printf ("7\n");
        } else{
            printf ("%d\n", sum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also just to clarify, that I'm still a beginner in programming (like only 2 months into C.SCi course), so if you could explain it to me like I'm not a expert that would be great.

Comment: You can combine the two parts of the if statement.  Just move the sum = sum % 40 outside the if statement.  If sum was already less than 40 the value doesn't change.

Comment: Check for errors (scanf failed or invalid value was entered) before you “accept” the input, i.e., don’t count the sum or increment number of values read until you get a valid input.

Comment: You might also consider ending on invalid input. That is, either let the user retry if the value is invalid (in which case you should probably print an error message) or alternatively stop the program on error. In the latter case you don’t necessarily need to read the number of rolls in advance - just read until the user gives a zero or whatever.

Comment: @Arkku, how do I not count the invalid input, so it doesn't get included in the sum?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` has no functionality to do what you want. You can just use an `if` to validate input.

```
if(scanf("%d", &diceResult) != 1 || diceResult < 2 || diceResult > 12) {
//handle invalid input here
}
```

If the input is invalid it is up to you what you want to do. You could ignore the input and ask the user to enter a valid number, you can quit the whole program or just ignore the error, or something else entirely.

You can also check the input repeatedly with an `while`:

```
while(scanf("%d", &diceResult) != 1 || diceResult < 2 || diceResult > 12) {
//prompt user to enter valid input here
}
```

As mentioned by chux, part of handling invalid input would be to cosume the invalid input and check for EOF.

---

The `scanf("%d", &diceResult) != 1` will assure, that scanf actually read exactly one number and no parsing errors occurred.

Comment: True, but `scanf` has more functionality than OP is using. How do you weed out an input of `abc` when the previous value of `diceResult` was `7`?

Comment: Good idea, we have to handle parsing errors or eof as well.

Comment: `while(scanf("%d", &diceResult) != 1 ....` is a poor idea.  Infinite loop on non-numeric input or `EOF`.

Comment: You're right, thanks. It forgot, that it doesn't consume the input in case of an error.

Comment: @churill, I tried this one, and while it did force you to re-input until it's a valid one, all of the previous invalid input is still calculated into the sum integer. How can I clear that invalid input buffer from the console?

Comment: @baronoke obviousely you should only sum up the value only _after_ you validated the input.  And you can just read the rest of input witth scanf. I recommend you do your own research ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;
    do
    {
        printf("give a number between [2-12]\n");
        scanf ("%d",&x);
    }
    while(x<2 || x>12);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use a do-while loop so that you only take the values that are between the 2-12 range. That way you can force the user to give an integer as an input that is in the range that you ask for, in that case from [2,12]. Otherwise the program will turn back and request a valid input again.